# What does cross-profession combo 'Cleansing Bolts' do?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I play Guardian and I have been playing with Greatsword which allows me a light field, which I can then combo with Whirl to get 'Cleansing Bolts'.

What does 'Cleansing Bolts' do? [Looking at the wiki page](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Cross-profession_combo) I can only assume that they remove conditions from allies that they strike. Does anyone have any line on what the various cross-combo effects actually do?

Comment: Are you asking about Cleansing Bolts in particular or cross-profession combo effects as a whole? If you're asking about the latter, I think that's potentially way too broad for a single question.

Comment: Edited to specify and avoid deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the wiki has now been updated and confirms that this combo will remove conditions from any ally hit by a projectile.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, both projectile and whirl finishers yield quite similar effects. The differences are

- *the trigger*: a projectile is a directed attack that moves through a combo field, while a whirl is an area effect that happens within a combo field;
- *the effect target*: the projectile finisher affects only the original target of the projectile, while the whirl finisher affects multiple (all?) enemies within an area of effect.

However, the effect of the combo itself is the same for both situations. A poison projectile poisons the affected target, and poison bolts do the same for all of its targets. The same seems to be true for the other combo field types. Hence, if triggered through a light field projectiles remove conditions from adjacent allies, so do the cleansing bolts.

Unfortunately, this is just based on my observations in the BWEs, and I cannot quote a reliable source on this.

Comment: I was more after the affects rather than the finishers.