# How do multiple combo fields interact with finishers?

Tags: guild-wars-2

If i have multiple combo fields below me and then do a whirl attack, which combo field effect get triggered?

In one of the boss battles i had a fire, poison and light combo field below me but it looked like only the light got triggered, did i just miss the notification or is it limited to "one finisher, one field"? If so, which field gets triggered first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some empirical testing (IE, playing my own character and trying it out) indicates that if you lay down two combo fields and then fire off a finisher, it'll combo off the *first* field.

Comment: Did you also test multiple combo fields that were at slightly different distances? It might just be "closest and if there are multiple at the same distance, first of those".

Comment: Looks like "oldest existing field within range". I'd have to get together with others to see if it prefers your own fields over someone else's but I suspect getting the timing close enough to conclusively prove that one way or the other isn't going to be practically viable.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find on the 'net, it is indeed just one field that will be triggered, just like you experienced.
Unable to find a clue as to what mechanism decides which field gets triggered though...

Edit: [this YT-video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7cQ3-gPNQw) should give you the answer, but I can't confirm it as I'm at work atm.

Comment: Sadly the video only covered projectiles travelling through multiple fields, not whirl, leap or blast finishers :-/

Comment: Hm, too bad.  I guess we'll have to play a lot more to figure it out for ourselves ;)

Comment: My  primary alt is a Guardian. With the Greatsword and the Purging Flame skill I can create two combo fields *and* execute a finisher through them, but this doesn't seem to create more than one effect at the same time. I'll do an actual test when I get home from work.

Comment: @Shadur I've been looking through the Guardian skills and i haven't seen a skill that the guardian can do to trigger his own combofields? Which are you talking about?

Comment: Purging Flames (and presumably other Consecrations) and the greatsword symbol skill (Second one you learn, don't recall the name offhand) both create combo fields. The third and fifth greatsword skills are whirl finishers, and the fourth is a leap finisher. I set off my own combo fields almost /constantly/.

Comment: See also [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72835/what-does-cross-profession-combo-cleansing-bolts-do)

Comment: The [GW2Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Combo)  states "Finishers can only interact with one initiator at a time.". But it does not tell which field gets activated.

Comment: @Shadur I think it's time for science then. I don't have the time to test it myself but whoever finds the solution gets my 150 points bounty.

Comment: @Shadur A how mega noobish of me, i figured that a light combofield needs to be finished by a light combofinisher, guess i was wrong :p

Comment: Looks like it triggers off the first field generated. I'd have to get together with a couple friends to see how this works with multiple people generating the fields or finishers.